# I need std::conditional but with more than two choices

Tags: c++, templates, std

Thing is, I have stack class template, and I want to decide which type of object I create based on, say, number, or char I get from file.
So instead of

```
if(T=='I')
    {
        myStack<int> teststack;
    }
else if(T=='D')
    {
        myStack<double> teststack;
    }
```

i wanna do something which allows me to use stack out of "if" scope

closest thing was std::conditional, but in my case that should work something like that:

```
template<int type, class first, class second, class third>
```

so I could use it like

```
   int i;
   input>>i;
   myStack<i> teststack;
```

And it should be first, second or third type based on number I have.
I know thats not best question, but I just kinda confused a lot

Comment: `myStack<i>` can't work since `i` is a run time variable.  You'd need to make the decision at compile time.  Best bet would most likely be to have a `std::variant<std::stack<int>, std::stack<double>, std::stack<foo> ...>`

Comment: `std::conditional` will not work at all, because its expression has be evaluated at compile time, and the value of `i` can only be known at run time. If you want to reduce the number of comparisons, use a `std::map< char,` _some-callable-type_ `>`.

Comment: @Nathan I think a variant will do more harm than good here, since it only hides what is really going on.

Comment: Maybe you can use `std::stack<std::any>` and dont actually care what T is?

Comment: Do you want to use the stack later, with the same code regardless of what kind of stack was created?  Your statement about, "use stack out of if scope," sounds like this might be what you are after.  If that's the case, then it seems like what you are after is really polymorphism.

Comment: thanks all! I know about conditional being evaluated at compile time, just said that like an example of what I need, and my brain were damaged at 5am :D Actually, I just tried to do it in more beautiful way, so @Spencer answered exactly what I need in this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you are acquiring the value of `i` (from a stream) means that its value can only be known at run time.

This means that `std::conditional` **will not work at all** for you, since the conditional expression has to be known **at compile time**.

A `switch` statement will get you what you need, but most implementations C++ essentially reduce a `switch` to a chain of `if` statements.

You will have `if` statements in whatever solution you come up with.

There is a well-worn C++ truism of "implement correctly first, then start optimizing".  So the naïve approach of a chain of `if` statements or even a `switch` statement is a perfectly acceptable way of doing this, and even **the best way**, until you discover you need something more efficient.

However, if you  want to eliminate the possibility of comparing `i` to every meaningful value, you can use something like a `std::map<char,` *`some-callable-type`* `>`. Look up the value of `i` in the map, and call the associated callable.

Try something like:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<map>
#include<functional>

template<class T> struct myStack{};

template<class T> int doStuff()
{
    myStack<T> mystack;
    return 0;
}


int main()
{
    char i;
    std::map<char,std::function<int()>> doIt{
        {'i', &doStuff<int>},
        {'d', &doStuff<double>,},
        {'l', []()->int{return 1;}},
        {'s', &doStuff<std::string>}
    };
    std::cin>>i;
    return doIt[i]();
}
```

(https://godbolt.org/z/fzhJc2)

You could even use a `std::array` if the number of possibilities is small.

Answer (score 3):

`std::conditional`s can be combined to form a switch:

```
using U = std::conditional_t<
    T == 'I',
    First, std::conditional_t<
    T == 'D',
    Second, Third>>;
```